# Form with Validation not Calling the Form Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a form that is embedded in a Wordpress page. The form can be seen here:

http://yellowsheetcoupons.net/get-emailed-coupons/

The first three fields need to be input, then it is to call a processing page to store the data into my database. Right now, I just have a test page that should echo "Submitted".

The problem is that the PHP page never gets called. Any idea as to why? You can see the form code and the JS validation function if you go to the page.

Thanks,

- Joe

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code here? It's easier to read here than to follow the link for many users.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are in fact getting "Submitted" returned from the server. However, the problem is that by doing:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data); // data contains "submitted"
```

in your ajax response handler, you are expecting to get a valid JSON object from your test.php page. A valid JSON response would be formatted like this:

```
{"success": "Submitted"}
```

FYI, I tested this by opening the javascript console when trying to submit your form, and the error is plainly visible there.

[image]

So, one solution is to try returning a valid JSON object instead:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array("success" => "submitted"));
?>
```

I can't run PHP to test this out, but you get the gist. Hope that helps!